# Get Laravel Controller response in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

How to extract "Title" in Javascript from an array returned from controller.

Controller Code :

```
public static function GetAcc($code)
{
    //
    $branch_id=session()->get('lbranch','0');
    if ($branch_id==0){
        $acc='';
    } else {
        $acc = Accounts::where('branchid',$branch_id)->where('code',$code)->get(['code','title','clbal']);
    }

    return $acc;

}
```

Javascript Code :

```
var x = document.getElementById("code").value;
var rec = $.get('/accounts/GetAcc/' + x);
```

This is the ResponseText I am getting :

```
"[{"code":101,"title":"This is a Long Supplier Name","clbal":null}]"
```

How can I retrieve "This is a Long Supplier Name" from responseText ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a completion closure to your `.get()` call:

```
$.get('/accounts/GetAcc/' + x, function(e){
    console.log(e);    
});
```

Your var will be e.something, if you still can't get it post what the console log writes!